# Не работает код на С++

Tags: c++

Задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код решения на С++, но результат он вывод неправильный. Помогите найти ошибку в коде.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float x, y, S, xy;
    cout << "Enter x and y:\n";
    cin >> x >> y;
    xy = x * y;

    if (0.5 < xy && xy < 10) S = exp(x - abs(y));
    else if (0.1 < xy && xy < 0.5) pow(abs(x + y), 1 / 3);
    else S = 2 * pow(x, 2);

    cout << "Result = " << S;
}
```

Comment: Замените `1/3` на `1.0/3`, или хотя бы `1./3`.  В `1/3` деление целочисленное, результат равен 0.

Comment: и вы забыли присвоить результат в "S"

Comment: @Harry Спасибо. Если произведение xy соответствует первому условию, то всё работает нормально. Если третьему, то тоже. А если попадает под второе условие `else if (0.1 < xy && xy < 0.5) S = cbrt(abs(x + y));` , то выводится не то, что должно быть. Условно я ввожу `x` и `y` - `0,1` и `0,2`. Ответ должен быть `0.669432`, но он `0.02`. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Почему ошибка? `0.1*0.2 == 0.02`, это значение подпадает под последний вариант ("иначе"), т.е. вычисление 2x^2, т.е. 2\*0.1^2 = 2\*0.01 = 0.02. Все правильно...

Comment: @Harry Ну я, конечно, болван... Спасибо вам большое!